# HTML script and javascript

Tags: javascript, php, sql

I am trying to to show the seats unavailable from the database

```
<?php 
$query = "SELECT * FROM booking;";
$result = mysqli_query ($connection,$query) or die ("<div class='alert alert-danger' role='alert'>You couldn't execute booking query</div>");

//Fetch all rows for each booking
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
extract ($row);
echo "
    <script type='text/javascript'>
        sc.get(['".$BOOKING_SEAT."']).status('unavailable');
    </script>";
echo "\n";
}
?>
```

This is what I see later:

```
<!-- Booking JavaScript -->
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/booking.js"></script> 
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/seat-charts.min.js"></script> 
<script type='text/javascript'>
    sc.get(['5_7']).status('unavailable');
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            sc.get(['5_8']).status('unavailable');
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            sc.get(['5_9']).status('unavailable');
        </script>

        <script type='text/javascript'>
            sc.get(['5_10']).status('unavailable');
        </script>
```

When I inspect the code I see what exactly I want but it is not working because it says the "Uncaught ReferenceError: sc is not defined".

The "sc" and "get" are from "js/booking.js" and "js/seat-charts.min.js".

UPDATE:

```
var price = 10; //price
$(document).ready(function() {
    var $cart = $('#selected-seats'), //Sitting Area
    $counter = $('#counter'), //Votes
    $total = $('#total'); //Total money

    var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
        map: [  //Seating chart
            'aaaaaaaaaa',
            'aaaaaaaaaa',
            'aaaaaaaaaa',
            'aaaaaaaaaa',
            'aaaaaaaaaa'
        ],
        naming : {
            top : false,
            getLabel : function (character, row, column) {
                return column;
            }
        },
        legend : { //Definition legend
            node : $('#legend'),
            items : [
                [ 'a', 'available',   'Option' ],
                [ 'a', 'unavailable', 'Sold']
            ]                   
        },
        click: function () { //Click event
            if (this.status() == 'available') { //optional seat
                $('<option selected>R'+(this.settings.row+1)+' S'+this.settings.label+'</option>')
                    .attr('id', 'cart-item-'+this.settings.id)
                    .attr('value', (this.settings.row+1)+'_'+this.settings.label)
                    .data('seatId', this.settings.id)
                    .appendTo($cart);

                $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length+1);
                $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length+1);   

                $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)+price);
                $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc)+price);   

                return 'selected';
            } else if (this.status() == 'selected') { //Checked
                    //Update Number
                    $counter.text(sc.find('selected').length-1);
                    $counter.attr('value', sc.find('selected').length-1);
                    //update totalnum
                    $total.text(recalculateTotal(sc)-price);
                    $total.attr('value', recalculateTotal(sc)-price);   

                    //Delete reservation
                    $('#cart-item-'+this.settings.id).remove();
                    //optional
                    return 'available';
            } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') { //sold
                return 'unavailable';
            } else {
                return this.style();
            }
        }
    });
    //sold seat
    //sc.get(['1_2', '4_4','4_5','6_6','6_7','8_5','8_6','8_7','8_8', '10_1', '10_2']).status('unavailable');

});
//sum total money
function recalculateTotal(sc) {
    var total = 0;
    sc.find('selected').each(function () {
        total += price;
    });

    return total;
}
```

**

> The problem is the "sc" is not global and we have to put it outside
>   the function

**

Comment: A little sidenote for when you become more experienced in client-server communication based on PHP and Javascript: retrieve data (preferably in [JSON](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) or [XML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/XML) format) using [asynchronous requests (AJAX)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/AJAX/Getting_Started) instead of writing Javascript with PHP directly. Nothing good ever came out from mixing programming languages. Well, maybe in the field of evolutionary algorithms, but certainly not in manually created code.

Comment: I do not know AJAX yet hehe

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the "sc" is not global and we have to put it outside the function

Answer (score 1):

You should init your `seatCharts`, e.g :

```
var sc = $('#seat-map').seatCharts({
    map: [
        'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
        'aaaaaaaaaaaa',
        'bbbbbbbbbb__',
        'bbbbbbbbbb__',
        'bbbbbbbbbbbb',
        'cccccccccccc'
    ],
    seats: {
        a: {
            price   : 99.99,
            classes : 'front-seat' //your custom CSS class
        }

    },
    click: function () {
        if (this.status() == 'available') {
            //do some stuff, i.e. add to the cart
            return 'selected';
        } else if (this.status() == 'selected') {
            //seat has been vacated
            return 'available';
        } else if (this.status() == 'unavailable') {
            //seat has been already booked
            return 'unavailable';
        } else {
            return this.style();
        }
    }
});
```

And try to add `ready` function since the `sc` variable will be declared after load otherwise the `sc.gets` will be triggered on load of the DOM:

```
echo "<script type='text/javascript'> $(document).ready(function(){";
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array ($result, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
    extract ($row);
    echo "sc.get(['".$BOOKING_SEAT."']).status('unavailable'); \n";
}
echo "});"
```

Check **[jQuery Seat Charts](https://github.com/mateuszmarkowski/jQuery-Seat-Charts)**.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thats what I have on "booking.js", look my update, as you can see there is a line that is comment about the unavailable seats that I am trying to modify in my new script

Comment: Thanks @ZakariaAcharki because now the code is better but still not working, "Uncaught ReferenceError: sc is not defined"